# Automatic push from different branch using Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops, production-environment

Maybe this is a stupid question, but I wanted to know in practice how this is handled.
Let's say what for a very simple project I have two branches on *GitLab*: "production" and "development".
Let's say I want to make changes in the development branch and after testing them, if the tests are successful push them directly to the production branch. Can this be done directly with gitlab ci/cd (maybe with a job where there is a `git push` to the other branch (after test job)) or is it not recommended in practice?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done from within the Job.
There can be a separate CI job (or same job with conditions) for dev and prod branches.
In the job you test and if successful, git push the changes to prod branch.

And your last question, whether it is recommended or not, it's upto your use case.
You are automating your task, which is the basis of DevOps.